# Can't stop a middleware chain in Go/Gin

Tags: go

I want to check session before continuing with a request and I have a middleware to check that session. This is the endpoint:

```
profile.Use(session.CheckSession())
profile.GET("/:pid", func(c *gin.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Hit :pid")
    c.File("../../html/profile.html")
})
```

And this is the `CheckSession()` middleware, values are placeholders atm:

```
func CheckSession() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        session := sessions.Default(c)
        userID := session.Get("user_id")
        firstName := session.Get("firstname")
        lastName := session.Get("lastname")

        if userID == nil || firstName == nil || lastName == nil {
            fmt.Println("No session")
            c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "/sign-in")
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Hit c.Next()")
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

The logs:
[image: Here are the logs]

At first, I hit `"/"` route, which redirects to `/profile/:pid` endpoint, which redirects to `/sign-in` endpoint in case of 'invalid' session. I get re-routed to the `/sign-in` endpoint, but the `/profile/:pid` endpoint still finishes execution, even without hitting `c.Next()` ever

Tried putting them in `if-else` blocks to make sure only one of `c.Redirect()` and `c.Next()` was being executed and so was happening, yet function was still passed and the chain didn't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by not aborting middleware chain manually.
`c.Redirect()` doesn't stop the middleware chain, you should manually call `c.Abort()` to prevent execution of the remaining handlers.

`c.Abort()` Tooltip:

> Abort prevents pending handlers from being called. Note that this will not stop the current handler. Let's say you have an authorization middleware that validates that the current request is authorized. If the authorization fails (ex: the password does not match), call Abort to ensure the remaining handlers for this request are not called.